# How to create extended back ground color in drop down list in Java

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created one drop down menu and added values to it and now I want to give back ground color as "black" to all values and whenever user moves cursor over anyone of the options it should change color to other (ex: grey).I can not add image here.Please ask questions for any clarification.

File.jsp

```
        <label for="select_problem">Problem</label>

          <select name="device" placeholder class="selectDropdown" id="problem_dropdown_menu">
            <option value="Select"> Select</option>
            <option value="Contact Support">Contact Support</option>
            <option value="Comment on site">Comment on site</option>
          </select>

          <div class="custom dropdown selectDropdown" id="problem_dropdown_menu">

            <a href="#" class="current">Select</a>
            <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="selected">Select</li>
                <li class="">Contact Support</li>
                <li class="">Comment on the site</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

File.css

```
#problem_dropdown_menu

{

display: block;

 position: relative;

  top: 0;

  height: 2.3125em;

  margin-bottom: 1.25em;

  margin-top: 0px;

  padding: 0px;

  width: 100%;

  background: white;

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #f3f3f3 100%);

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #f3f3f3 100%);

  -webkit-box-shadow: none;

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #f3f3f3 100%);

  box-shadow: none;

  font-size: 0.875em;

  vertical-align: top;

  border: solid 1px #cccccc;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know what you are trying, but is this something you wanted?

```css
option{
  background-color : black;
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<label for="select_problem">Problem</label>

          <select name="device" placeholder class="selectDropdown" id="problem_dropdown_menu">
            <option value="Select"> Select</option>
            <option value="Contact Support">Contact Support</option>
            <option value="Comment on site">Comment on site</option>
          </select>

          <div class="custom dropdown selectDropdown" id="problem_dropdown_menu">

            <a href="#" class="current">Select</a>
            <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="selected">Select</li>
                <li class="">Contact Support</li>
                <li class="">Comment on the site</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: I have created drop down menu which is having values as shown and I want to apply back ground color to values of drop down menu and after pop over on any values it should get highlighted with another color for which cursor currently pointing to.

Comment: So you want for every value a different color and when you move your mouse over a value, it should highlight a different color instead of the standard blue?

Comment: same back ground color for all values but when cursor moves on any of the value i.e current value should change its color (for ex: grey) rest of the  values should have same color.